# Align text to the middle of polygon, and border collapse in SVG

Tags: html, svg, polygon, text-align

All, 
Question 1: 
I have been experienced difficulties in aligning text to the middle of the polygons in SVG, HTML.
There are a number of polygons. But, I only put 3 up for the easiness. 
For each polygon, I have the points value for Xs and Ys.
Hence, It is possible to get an approximately average value of x and y, and use these values in "text" elements. 
It is acceptable to align text to the SVG polygons if there are only a small number of them.

So I wonder if there is a SVG property, or any other way to align the text to the polygon automatically? 
Such as text-align, or position: centre, which you don't have to calculate the x,y value, it will align to the middle of polygons?

Here is the JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/umb2fmuc/

HTML:

```
<svg height="503" width="900" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    <g id="Ashfield">
        <polygon points="536,379 535,377 536,374 539,368 541,367 541,363 539,363 540,359 546,362 557,362 559,358 559,359 565,358 568,359 567,363 563,368 564,382 562,386 558,386 554,390 554,392 552,392 551,395 547,397 547,399 545,398 548,392 548,386 546,385 537,386 536,379"/>
        <text data-brackets-id="152" x="536" y="380" style="font-size: 12px;"> Ashfield </text>
    </g>
    <g id="Auburn">
        <polygon points="437,360 438,358, 437,345 441,337 441,331 439,329 439,326 441,320 452,318 455,317 457,314 468,312 472,304 483,304 483,306 485,307 488,307 493,302 499,304 493,311 493,315 496,316 497,318 496,321 497,324 501,325 501,334 496,339 490,342 486,340 482,341 480,347 480,349 482,349 479,350 479,353 486,363 484,364 482,371 467,377 451,378 447,373 445,373 443,370 441,370 439,367 436,366 437,360"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Bankstown">
    <polygon points="403,430 405,428 405,425 399,418 399,405 402,405 404,403 404,400 397,394 397,390 393,389 393,383 394,382 399,383 402,372 405,369 406,365 408,364 413,353 421,360 423,360 436,370 438,370 438,372 443,374 451,381 468,380 478,375 480,375 481,380 485,380 486,378 489,377 485,402 489,404 494,404 488,406 486,413 478,422 468,425 467,430 461,431 461,443 462,449 464,450 464,469 467,472 468,476 462,477 456,481 443,483 441,487 438,489 438,491 430,490 430,486 426,486 422,490 420,486 424,483 424,481 417,475 417,473 414,470 406,469 406,464 408,463 407,457 404,455 399,455 395,446 391,445 394,442 393,432 395,432 397,429 399,431 403,430"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

As you can see, I use x, y to roughly align the text "Ashfield" to the polygon(Ashfield).

Question 2: 
As it shows, the border of polygon "Auburn" and "Bankstown" are having a small gap in between. How can I merge them together to make it looks like a single border, just exactly like the map?

Comment: I have answered your first question.  Please move your unrelated Q2 to a new question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `text-anchor="middle"`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextAlignmentProperties

It will centre the text horizonatally on the point you specify.  However there is no reliable way to center the text vertically, but using `dy="0.5em"` may be a reasonable approximation for you for a single line of text.  You can tweak the `dy` amount to suit the font you are using and it should work for any font size.

```html
<svg>

  <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="5" fill="red"/>
  <text x="150" y="75" text-anchor="middle" dy="0.5em"font-size="20">Here is some centred text</text>
  
</svg>
```